# POST request from react child component in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I am using the MERN stack (With react-router and redux) for my program.
In my application, I have a `<Navbar />` component as well as a `<SearchBar>` component.

I used create-react-app to handle the react side of things, and as i'm sure you all know, everything is ultimately contained within App.js
Within App.js, `Navbar` is outside of the react router switch statement like so.

```
 <Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <div>
   <NavBarContainer />
   <Switch>  
      <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
      <Route exact path="/ProfilePage" component={ProfilePageContainer} />   
      <Route exact path="/SearchPage" component={SearchPageContainer} />     
      <Route exact path="/LoginPage" component={LoginContainer} />
   </Switch>
 </div>
 </Router>
 </Provider>
```

My problem is that `SearchBar` is a child component of `Navbar` like so.

```
class Navbar extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
    ***navbar stuff
    {this.props.loggedIn && <SearchBar />} 
    ***navbar stuff
    )
  }
}
```

And when I try to make a POST request from `<SearchBar />` like this:

```
addSearch = (event) => {
  if(this.props.loggedIn){
    fetch('/api/SearchPage', {
      headers : {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"       
      },
      method :  'POST',
      body : JSON.stringify({
        username : this.props.username,
        search : this.search.value
      }).then(function(value){
        return value.json()})
      .then(function(data){
        console.log("SearchData", data)
      }).bind(this) 
    })
  }
}
```

Where `addSearch()` is called within the `SearchBar` with `onClick(this.addSearch)`.

When I do this, the POST request comes from whatever page is rendered under my `Navbar`!

My page says:
`Cannot POST /api/[Pagename}.js`

Whatever page is currently rendered under `Navbar` with react switch will replace `[Pagename]`

How can I make `<SearchBar />` create a POST request within itself?
Or, if that is not possible, how can I contain that post request within the `<Navbar>` component?

Something I'm considering, is that it has something to do with the fact hat I'm using a body parser, and the current body of the page happens to be whatever page is loaded.  However, I seem to define the body: within the POST request so this doesn't make much sense.

For now, i'm simply going to put all of the code and logic of the  `<SearchBar>` component within the `<Navbar>` and the search page, but I suspect that there is a much better way to do this (while leaving `<SearchBar>` within its own component).
Ideally, I'd like to send a POST request just from `<SearchBar>`.

I know I'm probably missing something common here.

Here is the endpoint in the express file (It is just set up for testing)

````
```
 app.post('/api/SearchPage', function(req, res done){  
  if(err) done(err);
  done(null, res.json({"Test" : "testobj"}))
}'
```
````

Comment: You are not making the POST request against an Express endpoint. You are doing it against a React component, and that's not possible.

Comment: How am I doing that? my fetch method goes to /api/SearchPage, and my node file has an app.post('/api/SearchPage') listener.
I"m assuming that because <SearchBar /> is a child component, you're saying that it  lives within the context of the parent components, and is never "seen" by express.
However, I already tried isolating all of the logic from <Searchbar /> into an entirely different page, and I get the same result.

Comment: Add the code for said endpoint then editing the original post, please.

Comment: Just added it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

From the given code, it seems like its the url in `fetch()` that is the issue here. Since you are only stating `'/app/SearchPage'`, then it is assumed to be part of the React app (which it is not, since its should hit your API endpoint).

You should try to insert the url for the endpoint. Is is sometimes running on a different port than the React application (depending on your setup). Endpoint could be something like `http://localhost:3050/api/SearchPage`, which should be set in the URL parameter of your `fetch()` method.

Comment: Well, i'm using both react-router and a proxy from react.
Here is my set up.
I have 2 `package.json` files in my program one of them is at `http://localhost:3000`
and the other is at `http:localhost:8080`
In package.json, there is a line of `"proxy : "http://localhost:8080"`.
Since i'm using react-router, my node.js file contains a line that defaults to `index.html` which really points to `App.js`.
Correct me if i'm wrong, but If I direct the URL to `localhost:8080` instead, wouldn't it just work for this example? What if i try to host it on some hosting platform like heroku or glitch?

Comment: BTW I tried just using
`http://localhost/api/SearchPage` and it worked!`
This way, I think react automatically reduces it down to the default (3000) and proxies over to the server (8080)

Comment: However, this didn't solve the problem for when <SearchBar> is a child component. It also didn't solve the problem when all of the searchbar logic was ported into my NavBar file. I now know that it has something to do with either react router, or body parser. My guess is body parser.

Comment: Try to be more explicit and put the entire url in `fetch()` thereby bypassing the proxy. Like this: `fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/SearchPage')...`. If MERN is contained in Docker, then you should be fine to host it anywhere, since it is isolated.

Answer (score 0):

I took a break today but the answer seems obvious at the moment.
When I do fetch(), all react does is append the URL (in this case /API/Page) to localhost/[pageimon]
Because all of my routing is handled client side by react router, my URL is whatever page I'm on. (I did not do any routing with express).
Since the navbar is out side of all switching (on purpose), whatever is contained in there will not make a successful post request, as all fetch calls will simply read the URL.

So I have to figure out a way to either bypass this (possibly a fetch parameter, or a react middleware module).